# JavaFX: How to calculate coordinates of ListCell before the ListView is shown the first time

Tags: java, javafx-2

I need a solution to get the coordinates from a `ListCell` of a `ListView` before the `listView` is displayed the first time. Because, I have to move a `Stage` (contains the `ListView`) which depends on these coordinates.

Comment: i think `.layoutX` and `.layoutY` is the thing you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Before stage is shown, no one node is allocated (as far as I remember, mostly - performance concern).

So, actual sizes and positions don't exist until content is rendered at the first time. So, to move the stage properly, you should add listeners on properties, describing position, and move stage on position changes.

Or move stage later, on some other event (mouse click, or smth else), when you can be sure, that coordinates exist and determined correctly.

Comment: Thank you for helping.

 But isn't there a possibility to draw in background a stage like Double buffering to get the right coordinates?

An other possibillity is maybe the onShown event?

Comment: To be correct, I cannot garantee, that at the moment of onShown, when stage is shown, that the scenegraph first pulse of rendering is done. It is questions of implementation - you can understand. And it need investigation, and you can try. The other thing - there is a special pipeline, - stub pipeline, which is used for test purposes... It is used for rendering, but without showing. Let me try to investigate it